# How to make sql trigger more than 2 definition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a main table in the sql, let's just ***tabel_a***.

In ***tabel_a*** mepunyai linkage to ***tabel_b***, ***tabel_c***, and ***tabel_d***

nah how if ***tabel_a*** removed then the other tables are also deleted by the id of each table. using the trigger in sql.
This is my code is wrong, how to fix

[image]

Comment: stop posting code as picture. post it as text. show your table structure. you can alter your table and define FK's for cascading delete

Comment: Use foreign key constraints with the cascading delete option.  That is the right way to implement this.